# Search in forum with innodb

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, innodb

I'm using `MySQL 5.3` and have no possiblilty to update it to a newer version (5.6 supports full-text search for innodb).

So my question is, should I user `Myisam` instead so I can use full-text search for my forums table?
The users need to be able to search in the table or should I solve it someway else, (what way?).

EDIT: Or should I use LIKE in SQL?

Comment: There is no such version as `MySQL 5.3`.

Comment: @eggyal Whatever, that what I was told. I can't make fields full text index, so it's not supported. What should I do?